# vector subscript out of range when try to acess a variable through multiple vectors

Tags: c++

before posting this error , i have checked that i am not trying to access vector's member that is out of scope , and yes the first member of a vector starts with index 0 and end with (vector size - 1)

I have strip down the non-relevant codes to display my error.

```
Voter v1("Ailee", 100, "Engineering", 012, d1, PositionType::Normal);
if (v1.getName() == "Ailee")
{
    cout << "\nTrue1\n";   // Yes
}

BallotPaper bp1(PositionType::President);
v1.AddBallotPaper(bp1);
if (v1.getBallotPaper(0).getPositionBP() == PositionType::President)
{
    cout << "\nTrue2\n"; //Yes
}

Candidate c1("Kookie", 100, "Engineering", 012, d1,  PositionType::Normal);
bp1.AddCandidate(c1);
if (bp1.getCandidate(0).getName() == "Kookie")
{
     cout << "\nTrue3\n";    // Yes
}

//cannot reach to candidate
if (v1.getBallotPaper(0).getCandidate(0).getName() == "Kookie")
{
    cout << "\nTrue4\n";   //error!
}
```

Here is my source file for relevant class:
For Voter class:

```
class Voter :public Member
{
 private:
   std::vector<BallotPaper> _bp;  //use vector for simple iteration
 public:
  Voter::Voter(std::string a, int b, std::string c, int d, Date e, PositionType f) : Member(a, b, c, d, e, f){}

void Voter::AddBallotPaper(BallotPaper b)
{
    _bp.push_back(b);
}

BallotPaper Voter::getBallotPaper(int index)
{
    return _bp[index];
}
}
```

For Ballot Paper class:

```
 class BallotPaper
 {
 private:
  PositionType _positionbp;
  std::vector<Candidate> _candidatesbp;   // only contain the required candidate
 public:
  BallotPaper::BallotPaper(PositionType a)
  {
    _positionbp = a;
  }

 void BallotPaper::AddCandidate(Candidate c)
 {
    _candidatesbp.push_back(c);
 }
 PositionType BallotPaper::getPositionBP()
 {
    return _positionbp;
 }
 Candidate BallotPaper::getCandidate(int index)
 {
    return _candidatesbp[index];
 }
 }
```

For Candidate class:

```
class Candidate :public Member
{
private:
 int _votecount;
 PositionType _position;
public:
 Candidate::Candidate(std::string a, int b, std::string c, int d, Date e, PositionType f) : Member(a, b, c, d, e, f)
{
 _votecount = 0;
}
}
```

Parent class:Member files

```
Member::Member(std::string name, int id, std::string course, int contact, Date joindate, PositionType currentposition)
{
 _name = name;
 _id = id;
 _course = course;
 _contact = contact;
 _joindate = joindate;  //in the format of 2018/10/22
 _currentposition = currentposition;
}
void Member::setName(std::string name)
{
 _name = name;
}
std::string Member::getName()
{
 return _name;
}
```

It seems that it cannot get the member variable from a vector of a vector OF a class.
Any inputs is well appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the definition of the Member class as well?

Comment: @P.W updated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `push_back` something into a vector, you make a copy.

This line: `v1.AddBallotPaper(bp1);` creates a copy of `bp1` and appends it to a vector inside of `v1`.
Later, when you change `bp1` by doing `bp1.AddCandidate(c1);`, the copy of it stored inside of `v1` is not affected.

Comment: So if I want to retain changes, i should use pointers?? or is there any way to make changes on bp1? perhaps i need to set it first?

Comment: @hopeestheim Pointers are one possible solution, but not necessarily the best one. I suggest simply doing `v1.AddBallotPaper(bp1);` *after* `bp1.AddCandidate(c1);`. Another option is to make `getBallotPaper` return a reference; then you'll be able to do `v1.getBallotPaper(0).AddCandidate(c1);`.

Comment: Yes that would be a legible method too. May i ask what do you mean by "return a reference"? Let's say if i do `v1.AddBallotPaper(bp1);` after `bp1.AddCandidate(c1)`,then if i do any changes in Candidate c1 variable, will it update the changes the next time i access c1 from bp1?

Comment: @hopeestheim With your current setup, only the changes made to `c1` before doing `bp1.AddCandidate(c1)` will affect what you get from `bp1.getCandidate(i)`. You should look up some tutorial on references; that's too much to explain in comments.